# why is my SSIS package stalling in execution mode

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Greeetings,

I'm trying to design and run a SSIS package.  It is a Type-1 update on a single key for a table of 80+ columns.

The rule is simple.  If PK exists, update, if not, insert.

below is an image of my Package's data flow:

[image]

as you can see, the image shows that the stage going into the SCD component is stuck on 669 rows.

The status in the log shows:

```
[SSIS.Pipeline] Information: Execute phase is beginning.
```

all other statuses appear normal.

However, nothing is moving.
how do I make this guy kick off the starting line?
Thanks much

Comment: probably could use some more detail so we might be able to understand why it is getting hung up.  To start with please add your configuration details on your SCD task.

Comment: My next step would be to identify the row that it is stuck on, (row #699 or #700, based on your graphic -- note that your graphic says 699, but your text says 669).  In a test copy of the package, you could even change your Source Component to be driven by a query (instead of a table), and in the query you would actually *select* that problem row... and see if the package then gets stuck on row #1.  Once you confirm the row is the problem, then I would recreate the update-or-insert in simple SQL in Mgmt Studio, and see if you get more information on the error, that way.

Comment: I would pull out of SSIS exactly what your copying/inserting, execute it in SSMS and you should see a much better error or at least see what it gets stuck on.